# Facebook PHP SDK get access token using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the following code to post to Facebook:

```
require('facebook.php');

$fb = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'MY APP ID','secret' => 'MY APP SECRET','cookie' => true));

$result = false;
$feed_dir = '/401868882779/feed/';  //to the UID you want to send to
$acToken = "MY ACCESS TOKEN";
$url = 'URL';
$link = $url . 'event.php?id=' . $id;
if (isset($picture))
{
    $picture = $url . 'uploads/' . $picture;
}
else
{
    $picture = $url . 'images/blank100x70.png';
}
$msg_body = array('access_token' => $acToken,'name' => $noe_unsecured,'message' => $link,'link' => $link,'description' => $description_unsecured,'picture' => $picture);

try
{
    $result = $fb->api($feed_dir, 'post', $msg_body);
} 
catch (Exception $e)
{     
        $err_str = $e->getMessage();
}
```

but I need to update the access token manually every time it changes. I am sure there's solution but I cant find it.. I tried lots of scripts and nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

Check: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setAccessToken/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on when you perform the wall post, you might need to request the **offline_access** permission. This will convert your access_token into a format that does not expire so there would be no need to refresh the token.

Comment: I requested offline_access but I still need to refresh the token. Maybe I didnt request it right?... what's the address to request offline_access?

Comment: You **don't** need the `offline_access` permission to post while the user is offline!

Comment: Isn't the point of offline_access to grant applications the ability to perform actions even while the user is signed out? That's what the name of the permission would even imply. I'll have to run some tests to see about this. Also, you can check what permissions are being granted by your access token using the [Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: Result of Debug Tool using my current working access_token (I censored some of the info)

access_token: 2705******47|30f5e4518a92******3a1afc.0-100000677***182|**9Th***pk1Nxum****JHUsfMDM

Info from debuger:
App ID: 2705******47,
User ID: 100000677***182,
Expires: Never,
Valid: True,
Origin: Unknown,
Scopes: create_note email offline_access photo_upload publish_stream read_stream share_item status_update video_upload

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution...**remove** the `access_token`!
You simply don't need it as long as you got the `publish_stream` permission!

Comment: If I remove the access_token, I need to change the `$msg_body = ... ` to `$msg_body = array('name' => $noe_unsecured ....`?

Comment: Yes just remove it. Once you have the `publish_stream` permission no need for the `access_token` **OR** `offline_access` permission

Comment: Used this http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=270566207647&connect_display=popup&v=1.0&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&cancel_url=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_failure.html&fbconnect=true&return_session=true&req_perms=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access

to grant publish_stream, and then removed the access_token from my script - but it didnt work (it published nothing on the wall..)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are multiple methods to do this:

 - you can use the method already provided in the PHP SDK `getAccessToken` which returns the current access token being used by the sdk instance, more info at [this url](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/).

 - However you need not use an access token to call the `api()` method, once you ask the user for the **publish_stream** permission, as already mentioned by @ifaour. Hence you can do something like [this example](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/), scroll to the subheading **Post a link to a User's wall using the Graph API**.

 - Then, you have another three options

i) either get a new access token using the method [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500), if you are posting when the user is currently using your app, otherwise you can try the next 2 options
ii) get **offline access**
iii) i'm not sure of this, but you might want to try with an app access token which can be obtained [this way](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin).

Comment: When I use `getAccessToken` I get the following error: "Invalid OAuth access token signature." - It doesnt give me the full access_token...

Comment: u get the error when you call the function or when you use the token after you get it from the call?

Comment: after I get it from the call.

Comment: Well actually u want to handle the expired access tokens, getAccessToken won't do that. U'll either have to send the user through the auth flow again, (that would seem like a page refresh to an already logged in user, and authentication to a logged out user, check http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500), or you ask for offline access, which is just another extended permission, so just put offline_access in your permissions scope.

Comment: I have offline_access permission - but it doesnt help (see the comment on Chaney Blu's answer)